# Como convertir hasharray a json

Tags: json, array, perl, hash, string

Estoy comenzando en perl y estoy batallando mucho con el siguiente problema, tengo un hasharray(se mira como json) que estoy tratando de convertir a un json regular para poderlo mostar en un pagina html;

este es un ejemplo de lo que sta en el hasharray:

```
[
  [
    {
      "time": 1555916399,
      "mes": 4, 
      "evento": [
        {
          "star": "1555855200",
          "year": "2019",
          "month": "4",
          "title": "Super car\'s day event",  
          "id": "1"
        }
      ],
      "dia": 21,
      "year": 2019,  
    },
```

el array contiene como 100 valores por eso no pongo todos;

el problema que estoy teniendo es el siguiente:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse ()
```

esta es la manera en la que estoy convieriendolo:

```
my $json_text = JSON::XS->new->utf8->encode ($myarray);
```

y cuando trato de mostrat $json_text en la pagina html el contenido se corta y no se porque, solo me muestra, al parecer \' esta generando el error pero no se como correjirlo

```
  [
      [
        {
          "time": 1555916399,
          "mes": 4, 
          "evento": [
            {
              "star": "1555855200",
              "year": "2019",
              "month": "4",
              "title": "Super car
```

Answer (score 3):

Esa barra inclinada está mal. De acuerdo al RFC4627, los únicos dos caracteres que deben escaparse son `\`, `"` y los códigos de control (los inferiores a `U+0020`).