# Error al usar JSON.parse donde un elemento de la cadena JSON contiene como parte del valor "{" o ":" o "["

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Recibo en la respuesta de $Ajax  una Cadena JSON que contiene elementos con caracteres especiales como "|", ":", "{", "}" etc.. y no puedo convertirlo en objeto con JSON.Parse para poder asignar el valor de dicha propiedad.
por ejemplo: recibo el JSON así:

```javascript
r='[{"AvisoCliente":"Dirigido al representante de |razonSocial|:\n\nPor este medio, le informamos que actualmente cuenta con {stock} folios de prepago. por lo que se le recomienda ponerse en contacto con |contacto| al Telefono :[telefono] para solicitar un nuevo paquete.","AvisoVentas":"Aviso:\nSe informa que el cliente |razonSocial| cuenta con |stock| folios de prepago, favor de ponerse en contacto con él para ofrecerle un nuevo paquete de prepago."}]'
```

Lo que quiero es poder retornar solo el valor de la propiedad "Avisocliente"  para poder ponerlo en una caja de texto html. pero al colocar la instrucción:

```javascript
JSON.parse(r);
```

Marca error y no separa las propiedades, le quito las "{}" los "|" las "[]" y de toda formas marca error en los dos puntos. de la palabra "Aviso:"

Comment: ¿Cuál es el JSON exactamente?  Si es el dato entre `[ ]` el mismo es válido, [como podrás verificar aquí](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), si no valida es por otro motivo o porque es otro el contenido que intentas validar, no éste.

Comment: "Marca error"? Entonces pon el error en la pregunta.

Comment: Creo que está respuesta puede marcarse como duplicada, pues ya se ha respondido [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/256488/101864). Solo tienes que poner `'\\n'` en vez de `'\n'`

Answer (score 1):

El problema es la secuencia `\n` en tu contenido json, te sugiero realizar el reemplazo por `\\n` y posteriormente podrás parsear sin problema

```javascript
r = r.replace(/\n/g,'\\n');
JSON.parse(r);
```

---

Ejemplo de uso:

```js
let r = '[{"AvisoCliente":"Dirigido al representante de |razonSocial|:\n\nPor este medio, le informamos que actualmente cuenta con {stock} folios de prepago. por lo que se le recomienda ponerse en contacto con |contacto| al Telefono :[telefono] para solicitar un nuevo paquete.","AvisoVentas":"Aviso:\nSe informa que el cliente |razonSocial| cuenta con |stock| folios de prepago, favor de ponerse en contacto con él para ofrecerle un nuevo paquete de prepago."}]';
r = r.replace(/\n/g,'\\n');
let parsed = JSON.parse(r);
console.log(parsed);
```